# Production Database Migrations ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working on my first ASP.NET MVC 4 app (using Entity Framework) and am a bit confused about the production database. Locally, the database seems to magically create itself (and the right tables) based on my models. Will this happen in production too with a non-express SQL Server... or do I manually need to import the schema?

Comment: This is all about Database Initializer see: http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/article.php/c19999/Understanding-Database-Initializers-in-Entity-Framework-Code-First.htm

Comment: Thanks. I was aware of most of that, just wasn't sure if that magic also happens automatically in production. The article was totally clear about that... so I am still a little unsure :)

Comment: If the application automatically run the migration in your development environment on start up, then it will also run it in production. Its the same software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will create whatever database is specified by the Connection String in your web.config if it does not exist.